# How to embed Tawk chat script in google AMP

Tags: javascript, amp-html, tawk.to

I need this Tawk chat script adding to my AMP page. I tried to add this script using amp-iframe. but it not working.

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
  var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
  (function(){
  var s1=document.createElement(“script”),s0=document.getElementsByTagName(“script”)[0];
  s1.async=true;
  s1.src=’https://embed.tawk.to/5bd98ae0476c2f239ff6b4d8/default';
  s1.charset=‘UTF-8’;
  s1.setAttribute(‘crossorigin’,‘*’);
  s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: You have your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732037/5893995

Answer (score 0):

See [spec](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec) here:

> it does not allow author written JavaScript beyond what is provided through the custom elements to reach its performance goals.

For `script` tag contents below:

> Prohibited unless the type is application/ld+json. (Other non-executable values may be added as needed.) Exception is the mandatory script tag to load the AMP runtime and the script tags to load extended components.

Afaik there is no support of chats in AMP.
Most you can is to add a tweet/facebook post and leave ability to comment there.
Allowed components are here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-twitter

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add an  and define the source as the link to tawk.to embbed:

```
<amp-iframe width="450"
  height="600"
     id="amptawk"
  layout="responsive"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"
  allowfullscreen
  frameborder="0"
  src="https://tawk.to/chat/xxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyy">
</amp-iframe>
```

You have to include this on the head:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```

I has worked for some time, but there seems to be a bug in tawk.to script which doesn't make it work anymore. You can try that.